Find maximum number of people that can go together
I have been asked this question in an interview.
There are n persons, where each person have their preferences with regard to the minimum and maximum number of people they can go together with. Their preferences are represented by 2D array peoplePreferences where peoplePreferences[i][0], peoplePreferences[i][1] represent the minimum and maximum number of people person[i] can go with. We have to return the maximum people that can go together.
peoplePreferences = [[1,4], [1,2], [2,3], [1,3]]
The expected output is 3 as person[0], person[2], person[3] can go together.

I could solve this in O(n^2). I tried to optimise it by performing range operations.

Take an extra array range of length global maximum of peoplePreference + 2(4+2=6 in example as the input would be 1 based index and 1 extra look at next step for this).
For each person, perform this range[person[i][0]]++ and range[person[i][1] + 1]--

So, in this case it would be [0, 3, 1, -1, -2, -1]

Use prefixSum on range-> [0, 3, 4, 3, 1, 0]

I could not proceed further. Was I going in right direction? If yes, how do I proceed?
If not, how to solve this efficiently?

You can treat each person's preference as an interval, then incrementally build up counts of the number of overlapping intervals as typical. Additionally, at each step you want to check if this count is at least as large as the preference value itself (and clamp it if so). There's also some edge cases to tiptoe around regarding duplicate start/end positions, fence post errors for inclusion / exclusion, whatnot.
In code:
from itertools import accumulate, pairwise
from collections import Counter

def solve(preferences):
    endpoint_counter = Counter()
    for start, end in preferences:
        endpoint_counter[start] += 1
        endpoint_counter[end + 1] -= 1

    endpoints, deltas = zip(*sorted(endpoint_counter.items()))

    return max([min(end - 1, count)
            for (start, end), count in zip(pairwise(endpoints), accumulate(deltas))
            if start <= count], default=0)

The time complexity is dominated by the sorting operation, making it O(n log n) for comparison-based sorting (as is done in Python), or O(n) if you (can) use counting sort.

A C++ solution.  Dillon's endpoint_counter and my delta serve the same general purpose, with delta specifically tracking - as you move from delta[n] down to 1, changes in the number of participants willing to join a group of n people.
O(n) space (for delta) and time complexity.
int f(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>& c) {
    int n = c.size();
    std::vector<int> delta(n + 1);
    for (auto [from, to] : c)
        if (from <= n) {
            --delta[std::max(0, from - 1)];
            ++delta[std::min(n, to)];
        }
    int best = 0;
    int matched = 0;
    for (int group_size = n; group_size; --group_size) {
        matched += delta[group_size];
        best = std::max(best, std::min(matched, group_size));
        if (best >= group_size) return best;
    }
    return best;
}


Store the data from peoplePreferences in two counting maps: minPreference and maxPreference. By counting map, I mean that the key is the min or max preference, and the value is the number of people with that preference.
E.g., for peoplePreferences = [[1,4], [1,2], [2,3], [1,3]]:
minPreference = { 1 => 3, 2 => 1 }
maxPreference = { 2 => 1, 3 => 2, 4 => 1}

Then go through the possible number of people, call it i, keeping track of the count of people satisfied with i people going together. If the count is ever >= i, then i is valid (there are at least i people willing to go in a group of size i).
initialize:
i = 10
willing_people = 0
best_solution = 0

loop until i == n:
i += 1
willing_people += minPreference[i]
if willing_people >= i then best_solution = i
willing_people -= maxPreference[i]

Running this on your data: (WP == willing people)
i, WP (inc min_pref), best_solution, WP (exc max pref)
0, 0, 0, 0
1, 3, 1, 3
2, 4, 2, 3
3, 3, 3, 1
4, 1, 3, 0

Final best solution is 3, as desired.
